# Does object have to be destroyed when a new object is assigned to its address?

Tags: c++, c++17, destructor, temporary, copy-assignment

Consider following code.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

constexpr size_t TOTAL = 2;

class thing
{
private:
    inline static size_t NEXT_ID = 0;
    size_t id;

public:
    thing() : id(NEXT_ID++)
    {
        printf("Thing %zd created.\n", this->id);
    }
    ~thing()
    {
        printf("Thing %zd destroyed.\n", this->id);
    }
};

class container
{
private:
    inline static size_t NEXT_ID = 0;
    size_t id;
    thing* things;

public:
    container() : id(NEXT_ID++)
    {
        this->things = new thing[TOTAL];
        printf("Container %zd created.\n", this->id);
    }
    ~container()
    {
        delete[] this->things;
        printf("Container %zd destroyed.\n", this->id);
    }

    thing& at(size_t idx)    // this is the important method
    {
        return this->things[idx];
    }
};

int main()
{
    container c;
    c.at(0) = thing();   // here is the problem
    return 0;
}
```

The output is something I didn't expect.

```
Thing 0 created.
Thing 1 created.
Container 0 created.
Thing 2 created.
Thing 2 destroyed.
Thing 1 destroyed.
Thing 2 destroyed.
Container 0 destroyed.
```

I know that `Thing 2` was a temporary object, that's why it was destroyed twice. I have a few questions about what happened to `Thing 0`.

- Why wasn't `Thing 0` destroyed?
- Will there be a memory leak?
- Do I have to destroy `Thing 0` somehow or was it overwritten successfully?

Comment: You may be interested in the address sanitiser, although your username makes me think you might already know about it!

Comment: When you assign `Thing 2` to `Thing 0` the `id` member also gets assigned.

Comment: If you want to know the exact object that is being created and destroyed print `this` (which will not change for an object), not the `id` that is copied by the copy constructor of `Thing`.

Comment: @WernerHenze Printing `this` instead of `id` reveals that top`Thing 0` and bottom `Thing 2` is the same object. So no memory leak was created. You can post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: as you use `inline static` which is a c++17 feature, u should definitely use `#include <cstdio>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no double call to a destructor for the same object. The problem is only in your output. You are printing the `id` but the copy assignment in `c.at(0) = thing();` copies the `id` from the temporary object to the one in the container. That is the reason that you see two "Thing 2 destroyed." and no "Thing 0 destroyed.".

If you want a better logging mechanism you can print the `this` pointer. The address of an object does not change over the lifetime of an object, it is a unique identifier for an object. Of course for convenience you can additionally print the `id`.

```
printf("Thing %p %zd created.\n", static_cast<void*>(this), this->id);
printf("Thing %p %zd destroyed.\n", static_cast<void*>(this), this->id);
```

That should give you some output like this (of course 0x11111111, 0x22222222 and 0x33333333 will look different in your case):

> Thing 0x11111111 0 created.
> Thing 0x22222222 1 created.
> Container 0 created.
> Thing 0x33333333 2 created.
> Thing 0x33333333 2 destroyed.
> Thing 0x22222222 1 destroyed.
> Thing 0x11111111 2 destroyed.
> Container 0 destroyed.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's `<void*>` not `<void>`. Here is an [example](https://repl.it/repls/FineMassiveAutosketch#main.cpp).

Comment: @sanitizedUser Of course. I changed that. BTW, next time feel free to just do the change in my posting :).

Comment: I couldn't change it. It was just two characters. There is a limit of 6 characters for edits.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
c.at(0) = thing();
```

there is used the implicitly defined by the compiler copy assignment operator. So the data member `id` of the object referenced by the expression `c.at(0)` becomes equal to the id of the temporary object created by the expression `thing()` that is equal to `2`.

In this statement the temporary object is created and at the end is destroyed

```
Thing 2 created.
Thing 2 destroyed.
```

Now the object `c` contains two sub-objects `thing` stored as elements of an array. The sub-objects have id(s) `2` and `1`.

They are deleted in the reverse order relative to creating of them

```
Thing 1 destroyed.
Thing 2 destroyed.  // previously it has id equal to 0
```

So the program does not have a memory leak. All created objects were successfully deleted as it is seen from the program output.